# how can I solve ora 12560 TNS protocol adaptor error

Tags: oracle, ora-12560

I'm running ORACLE 11gR2 through Windows server 2008 R2. Because of some reason shutdown database with "shutdown immediate" command, but when I need to startup again database, this error message is appear:
"ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error"
about ORA 12560 I consumed many time through internet for finding soloution but all of the is very basic guide that could not solve my problem. please consider to my problem with following below image:
1. when I want to startup database:
[image]

2. set oracle_sid in command prompt and check in windows environment variables:
   [image]
3. check lsnrctl status:[image]
4. tnsping:
   [image]
5. check windows oracle service:
   [image]

so, according those images everything looks fine but my database wont to start again I will be thankful if I have your clear, correct and tested solution for my problem

Comment: What happens if you replace `sqlplus /nolog` with `sqlplus / as sysdba`?

Comment: there is no make any difference and same error has been appear

Comment: You've set the environment variable `ORACLE_SID` to `orcl`, but the SID in your tnsnames.ora file and in your `tnsping` screenshot uses `orcl113`, which is likely the correct SID.  What happens if you set `ORACLE_SID` to `orcl113`?

Comment: My problem has been solved. At first I stop oracle service, after that delete listener.ora and create listener again, and set oracl_sid to orcl in environment variable manually and start oracle service again. Thanks for your help and consideration @LukeWoodward

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of things that might be happening here.

I continue to have issues with databases registering properly with the listener. Make a backup of the listener.ora file %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\listener.ora and add an entry similar to the following to the SID_LIST. Your ORACLE_HOME path will most likely be different than mine:

```
  (SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = RDEV.world)
  (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME = RDEV)
)
```

Restart the listener and see if you can connect:

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

The following entry added to the sqlnet.ora file also helps. Again, backup before editing

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = WORLD
```

This allows you to reference the database as `ORCL` or `ORCL.WORLD`

These fixes have worked on Oracle 11 and 12 databases.